# Exposing multiple iterable interfaces

Tags: c++, loops

A `Scene` contains a list of `Shape`.

Each `Shape` contains:

- Its `std::vector` of `Vertex` (with surface normal, texcoord, 3-space position)
- Its `std::vector` of `Triangle` (tied up vertices, for mesh intersection)

I'd like to make the `Scene` object iterable *both* as a collection of `Vertex`, and a collection of `Triangle`, in a **not-so-messy** way.

Currently what is required is to walk the triangles: (C# syntax here):

```
foreach( Shape shape in Scene )
{
    foreach( Mesh mesh in shape.meshGroup.meshes )
    {
        foreach( Triangle tri in mesh.tris )
        {
            // work with tri
        }
    }
}
```

The triple nested `for` isn't nice to see, and of course C++ syntax is hella worse, using either counters i, j and k or using `::iterator`s..

To access each `Vertex`:

```
foreach( Shape shape in Scene )
{
    foreach( Mesh mesh in shape.meshGroup.meshes )
    {
        foreach( Vertex v in mesh.verts )
        {
            // work with v
        }
    }
}
```

Since walking all Triangles/Vertices *is expensive to begin with*, what's the best way to do this?  (Assume its necessary to hit *every* `Triangle` / `Vertex`, so no need for spatial subdivision algorithms etc)

You can use any C++ 0x features (VS-2010 enabled), lambda included.

Comment: Is this an issue because you need to repeat the same loops in multiple places in your code?

Comment: You would do `for (Vertex & v : shape.vertices()) /*...*/`, where `Shape::vertices` returns a range. Similarly for triangles. How you implement `Shape::vertices` is another matter entirely.

Comment: As an addendum, I've missed `yield` in C++ for a while now.

Comment: Wouldn't you overcount vertices massively, since each vertex can belong to arbitrarily many triangles?

Comment: @KerrekSB Short answer: No :).  Details: The `verts` array is basically the vertex array used for drawing.  It can be indexed, which means vertices would not be repeated (there is a separate array called `indices` which indicates drawing order.) The `tris` list is auxiliary, used only for things like mesh intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create functions which iterate over all the elements and call a function object:

```
template <typename F>
inline void for_each_vertex(Scene& scene,F f)
{
  for (Shape& shape : scene) {
    for (Mesh& mesh : shape.meshGroup.meshes) {
      for (Vertex& vertex : mesh.verts) {
        f(vertex);
      }
    }
  }
}

template <typename F>
inline void for_each_triangle(Scene& scene,F f)
{
  for (Shape& shape : scene) {
    for (Mesh& mesh : shape.meshGroup.meshes) {
      for (Triangle& triangle : mesh.tris) {
        f(triangle);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do

```
for_each_vertex(scene,[](Vertex& vertex)(/* work with vertex */});
for_each_triangle(scene,[](Triangle& triangle)(/* work with triangle */});
```

This should have the same performance as your original code, but you won't have to write the same loop structure multiple times throughout your program.

Comment: Note however that this construction inverts the iteration logic and makes it slightly less useful (it prevents you from using any of the standard range algorithms, for example).

Comment: I thought of this, but isn't the lambda going to incur like a __huge__ performance overhead (over 1,000,000-odd vertices)?

Comment: Ah yes you've inlined it, hmm, let me test it

Answer (score 0):

If all the processing is done in the inner loop, you could create a custom iterator which iterates over all three levels, and produces `(Shape*,Mesh*,Vertex*)` triples, handling the logic to move e.g. to the next `Mesh` once all the `Vertex`es have been iterated over for the current `Mesh`.

If you want to do *some* processing in the middle or outer loops, you could add some hooks, or for instance return a `(Shape*,NULL,NULL)` triple for the first time through a new `Shape`.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to expose separate 'logical containers' into a big (multi-)container class:

I define a method 'getMeshRange()`,`getShapeRange()` etc.

If you use the boost range library, you could return `boost::iterator_range<const Shape*>`, `boost::sub_range<std::vector<Vertex> >` etc.

In practice, IIRC, to satisfy the Range concept, you can just return `std::pair<const_iterator, const_iterator>`.

A range can be used as follows:

```
for (It it = std::begin(X.getMeshRange()); it!= std::end(X.getMeshRange()); ++it)
{ 
    // use *it
}
```

or in C++0x

```
for (auto& mesh : X.getMeshRange())
{
    // use mesh
}
```

With Boost Range Algorithm, you can do anything that you could with a 'regular' container:

```
const Shape& shape = *std::min_element(X.getShapeRange());
```

Comment: I think the question is more about how to link all the vertex containers to get one iterable range.

Comment: Well uh, actually having split iterable ranges would be useful. I don't want to use Boost.

Comment: @bobobobo Remember: you don't have to use boost. A pair of iterators models a range just fine (`for (const T& i: make_pair(it1, it2))` will do nicely on c++0x)